# imagecopyresized expects parameter error: trying to make thumbnail without distortion

Tags: php, image, resize, crop

I'm trying to make an image into a thumbnail with a certain size without distortion (if image is rectangular).

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 30");
$img = 'img/'; //this is where my files are.
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

$imageName = $img.$row['images'];
$tempImage = imagecreatetruecolor(150,150);
$thumbnail = imagecopyresampled($tempImage,$imageName,0,0,0,0,150,150,150,150);
echo $thumbnail;
?>
<div id='<?php echo $imageID; ?>' class='images' style=''>
<img src='<?php echo $imageName; ?>' style='height:150px;width:150px;'/>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

This is how my code looks right now and I need some help. I have a code:

```
<img src='<?php echo $imageName; ?>' style='height:150px;width:150px;'/>
```

just to see how it looks like with the height and width style, but of course this shows distortion.

When I `echo $thumbnail;` it gives me imagecopyresized() expects parameter error.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The `$imageName` you're passing in is just a filename, it appears. YOu have to provide a GD image handle for both the source AND destination arguments:

```
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('somepicture.jpg');
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor(150,150);
$status = imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, etc....);
```

Comment: i did `$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('img/somepicture.jpg');` but its only displaying the number 1?

Comment: That number is the internal GD handle for the image. it is NOT the image itself.

Comment: You have to serve it up via a seperate request, or save it to a file and point your HTML at that file. You can't create the image and serve it up within your script as is - you can't (with certain exceptions that DO NOT apply here) mix an image and html within the same script.